# Is it possible to prevent normal non-admin users from creating admin users in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware6

I wonder if it is possible in Shopware 6 to prevent non-admin users to create new user-accounts, but restrict them from creating admin-users. We have such a usecase, where we want a specific user group to create new user accounts, but they shouldn't be able to create them with admin privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible at this time to differentiate permissions like that within the user management. This would need to be an additional permission outside of the scope of regular CRUD permissions of `user` entities, as the admin toggle is just a boolean field of the entity. I think it could be a useful addition though, so maybe consider [creating an issue](https://issues.shopware.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I created a new entry for this at feedback.shopware.com as we were told at the SCD developer day ;) 
https://feedback.shopware.com/forums/942607-shopware-6-product-feedback-ideas/suggestions/46766755-new-privilege-for-creating-admin-users

Comment: Probably a user should always be only able to create another user with the same roles at maximum - otherwise this allows to escalate privileges as soon as the "create user" permission is given.